# Account Currency field in Screen Flow only rendering as text field, how to show picklist options?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow

I am currently working with a multi-currency Salesforce org and have been trying to add the "Account Currency" field on a Screen Flow. However, the field only renders as a text field and doesn't show any currency picklist options.

I have checked that the "Account Currency" field is set up as a picklist with valid currency values in the object's field settings. Additionally, I have also checked that the picklist values are visible to the profiles assigned to the user.

I am wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue and knows how to resolve this problem? I would greatly appreciate any insights or potential solutions to this problem.

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot you're using a Currency input component, which is for capturing currency values rather than picklist options.

When using a picklist value, you've got a couple of options in Flow:

1. Use a Picklist Choice Set (which will retrieve the values from an existing picklist field) and expose this using a [Picklist component](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_picklist.htm&type=5)
2. Use the [Record Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_elements_screen_object_field.htm&type=5) functionality with your picklist field to allow users to select options. This requires you to use a Record variable to store the input but does provide better support for record types as it will automatically manage which picklist values should be visible.